# SVN - handshake failed : SSL error

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, sslhandshakeexception

I am unable to update or commit to svn from a machine that did not have this problem until recently. I updated the tortoise svn client. I can delete the folder and pull a new copy down every time but cannot commit or update.

Unable to connect to a repository at URL

OPTIONS SSL handshake failed: SSL error: sslv3 alert illegal parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolve that problem as follows:

1. Go with Chrome (or other browser that allows to save the certificate) to svn address
2. Save the certificate file
3. Install it into Trusted Root Center of Certificates (that could be named with other words, I dont know how exactly that named in english)

Also, changing svn client (from svn tortoise) to another solves problem too.

Answer (score 4):

You're almost certainly using an SVN client which is to old.

Comment: I have this same problem... even though my SVN client is fully up to date.

Comment: @medvedNick: Nope... still an issue for me.

Comment: @BG100, see my answer here, hope it would help

Answer (score 0):

Probably the antivirus broke the certificate. Shut down the antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off the proxy server settings for your SVN client if accessing an internal repository.

In order to access an external svn repo to checkout samples from the web, I had enabled the proxy settings in TortoiseSVN under.  Settings->Network->Enable Proxy Server

However I forgot to disable it and I was receiving the above error when accessing our internal repo.  This was happening Tortoise SVN client and eclipse svn was also not working properly. I turned off the proxy settings and both started working fine.