# SSL handshake failed error?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

SSL handshake failed: SSL error: sslv3 alert illegal parameter.

This is the error that I get when I try to import **a big** file to SVN. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the server is forcing you to use SSL v3, which the SVN client is not using for the connection.

Try connecting via an up-to-date browser, or from the command line -- e.g. `curl` with SSL v3 specified -- and verify that is the case.

Once you have verified this as the cause, see how your SVN client can solve it.

Comment: hmm. I can enter the https link in browser and it works. Now what?

Comment: Great.  To solve the issue depends on your OS and your SVN client, see how you can make your SVN client use SSL v3. Also, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052927/svn-handshake-failed-ssl-error and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119237/tortoisesvn-suddenly-raises-options-ssl-handshake-failed-ssl-error-sslv3-aler

Comment: I tried both without success. But thanks for your effort. I think it's a problem with the support of the company that I work.